# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/ads/AbstractAdListener.class

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-audience-network

I am trying to implement facebook mobile ads in an android app. Everything went fine but in build gradle i m getting error.

> Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/facebook/ads/AbstractAdListener.class.

And build.gradle codes are

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {

    compileSdkVersion 23

    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.mohit.warmodroid.practicefbads"

        minSdkVersion 15

        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
 }
 dependencies 
{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile ('junit:junit:4.12'){

        exclude group: 'com.facebook.ads', module: 'classes.jar'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:design:23.0.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.ads', module: 'classes.jar'
    }
    compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.7.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.ads', module: 'classes.jar'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

I tried everything availble on stackoverflow.com but unable to clear it.
Please help me out.

Comment: I would try this on one of the sample projects bundled with the SDK, then try with different build settings (minify enabled/disabled, proguard and without ... etc)

Answer (score 4):

In the Gradle settings and project configurations there is an old version of `AudienceNetwork.jar`, existing in the `\libs` folder. Remove this jar file from `\libs` and rebuild the project: this should fix the problem.